UI Kitten with Expo Navigation and Theming not working together?
I'm trying to make use of UI Kitten in my Expo React Native project. From the UI Kitten documentation, it seemed that Expo Navigation would not work and that I would have to replace Expo Navigation with using the regular React Navigation libraries, which I have done.
The problem I'm having is that the Tab.Screen is partially taking the colors from the UI Kitten theme I have set up, meaning that the content background is using the correct color, but the headerStyle.backgroundColor and tabBarStyle.backgroundColor are unset so are not using the correct color. I find that i can set these manually in the Tab.Screen.options and have tried to obtain the color palette from the UI Kitten hook and do something like const themeColors = useTheme() and eva[theme] which yields this JSON:
{
  "color-primary-100": "#F2F6FF",
  "color-primary-200": "#D9E4FF",
  "color-primary-300": "#A6C1FF",
  "color-primary-400": "#598BFF",
  "color-primary-500": "#3366FF",
  "color-primary-600": "#274BDB",
  "color-primary-700": "#1A34B8",
  "color-primary-800": "#102694",
  "color-primary-900": "#091C7A",
  "color-primary-transparent-100": "rgba(51, 102, 255, 0.08)",
  <... and so on ...>
}

Which seems like more than I should need to do based on the UI Kitten documentation and examples. I found the doc page on "Using Theme Variables" and section Declare Custom Component seems like it could work, but my code is pretty basic, it just uses the regular React Navigation libs in a simple basic way, and it just seems like I'm missing something to get theming to work fully and take the theme colors fully instead of partially.
So, my questions are:

Is it the case that I cannot use Expo's File-based routing and must instead fallback to using React Navigation directly? If I can use Expo's File-based routing, is there sample code for this?
If I must use React Navigation directly, how should I apply the theme from UI Kitten to the Navigation components such that the themes are applied completely?

Thanks!
UI Kitten and Eva version



Package
Version




@eva-design/eva
2.2.0


@ui-kitten/components
5.3.1



